# How to pause the timer with clearInterval

Tags: reactjs

I try to write a pomodoro, using the setInterval and clearInterval function to set up the timer, but when I use clearInterval to pause the time, it's still ticking, and the value of interval Id become undefined.

```
const [remainSecond, setRemainSecond] = useState(250);
const [start, setStart] = React.useState(false);
const startTime = Date.now()
let interval = undefined;

const handleCountDown = () => {
      setStart(!start)
      if (!start) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (remainSecond > 0) {
            const pastSeconds = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000)
            const remain = (timer - pastSeconds)
            setRemainSecond(remain < 0 ? 0 : remain);
          } else {
            handleStop();
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
  };
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `setStart` function as well?

Comment: setStart is the react useState function, it's just change the var start value.